# Getting InvalidArgumentException

Tags: selenium

```
package trails2110;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Demo01 {
    WebDriver driver;
    
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Eclipse\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        System.out.println("1");
        driver= new ChromeDriver();
        System.out.println("2");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        String url= "www.hotstar.com";
        System.out.println("3");
        driver.get(url);
        System.out.println("4");
        String Title=driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println(Title);
    }
}
```

In Console till 3 its getting printed.
I have latest version of chrome and latest version of chrome driver for it.
i tried with multiple drivers didnt work.
am i missing something?

I am able to route to the url with the following code

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Eclipse\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
        String url = "https://www.google.com";
        String script = "window.location = \'"+url+"\'";        
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script);
```

any reasons its not happening with get() method and happening with JavascriptExecutor ?

Comment: Might just need the full url... so: String url= "https://...";  (There is some validation in the .get() method... it'll throw "InvalidArgument" if deemed not valid...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare the URL with its protocol. So

```
String url= "www.hotstar.com";
url = "https://" + url
```